# Overriding dependencies property value in Spring

Tags: java, spring

In my Spring project I am using a dependency project developed in Spring. This dependency has its own properties file and have defined a property which points to `localhost`. Now in my setup, I want this property to be pointing to another URL but not localhost. I am trying to override this in my properties file using `addFirst` method of property sources, but the dependency still loads the original property value.

```
ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
//here i overload the props
environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(
                new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:conf/app.properties")); 
LOG.debug("dependency property: " + applicationContext.getEnvironment().
getProperty("server.hostname")); // here it prints the overloaded value in app.properties
```

When I print the overloaded property I get the overloaded property value, but when the program gets executed it points to localhost. Is this the way to override dependent properties ? Spring version is 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is, that in the ProperySources the last one wins.

(Its like in a Database, the last one that writes wins).

Try to use simply `add`.

Comment: Is there an `add` method on Property Sources implementation. I am using Spring 3.2

Comment: You are right. Tried loading the same property again in the main app as the last file. In fact the last one has almost all of the props.